# playing video in listview

Tags: android, listview, video

I want to play **videos(a video in a row)** in rows of a **ListView**.Also I want to play one video at a time and when my app goes to background, video should stop playing.Is there any way to achieve the same?

Comment: Did you check the `Activity Life Cycle` discussions before putting this question?

Comment: @Sufian This time my question consists of two parts.

1) I want to play one video at a time in my ListView and I don't think it has any relation with Activity's Life Cycle.

2) I want to stop video from playing when my app goes to background. This really has link with Activity Life Cycle i.e I have to do something in OnPause or OnStop of my Activity. But all I was asking what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`onPause()` and `onStop()` are an `Activity`'s life cycle methods. Please refer to [this](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-activity) and [this](http://smarterappsguidelines.gsma.com/content/background-foreground-modes-1).

Generally on SO it's discouraged to ask for a solution before stating what you have come up with. Anyway, you can keep a field to store a `VideoView` and other needed information in your `Activity` and set/get when you are playing/stopping.

Comment: I was saying that first part of my question has nothing to do with Activity's Life Cycle.I was talking about ListView to play one video at a time and there is nothing an Activity's Life Cycle can do.Coming to second part, I agree that second part has something to do with Activity's Life Cycle.